Why pullback of ideal sheaf should be the conormal sheaf?
I'm sorry that this isn't really a math question, but this gap between my intuition and the truth bothers me. For closed subvariety (for simplicity) with ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}$, the pullback $i^*(\mathcal{I}/\mathcal{I}^2)$ is equal to $i^*(\mathcal{I})$ and this is a conormal sheaf. However, my interpretation of an ideal sheaf was 'functions vanishing at the subvariety', for example, it corresponds to just $I$ when the subvariety is $V(I)$ in the affine case. Therefore I thought it would be more reasonable for the pullback to be either zero (as $I$ vanishes on subvariety) or just $I$ itself (which formally doesn't make sense). In other words, it feels 'very lucky' to me that pullback suddenly sees only 'first-order terms'. I would be satisfied if some explanation could be given, at least for the simplest case, the cotangent space $m/m^2 = m\otimes_A A/m$. This simple algebraic equality looks weird when I think about these things. Should I just ignore all this analogy as $I/I^2$ is no longer a sheaf of ideals?

I'm not sure how an answer to this post could look like. Did you compute some examples? Maybe easy ones, like $\mathbb A^1 \subset \mathbb A^2$ or $\mathbb P^1 \subset \mathbb P^2$.

All of this rests on the fact that $ I \otimes_A A/I = I/I^2 $. The pullback isn't $ 0 $ because we're looking at functions on the subvariety, i.e. looking at $ A/I $-modules

I found the following example particularly satisfying. Let $X$ be a noetherian reduced one-dimensional scheme with irreducible components $X_i$, with corresponding ideal sheaves $\mathcal{I}_i$. Then the product of all such ideal sheaves $\mathcal{I}_1\cdots\mathcal{I}_k=0$ (and it allows us to use some kind of cohomological induction on the number of irreducible components, the reason I originally considered this).
Algebraically, I could give the following proof. We use the fact that minimal prime consists of zero-divisors. Let $\mathfrak{p_i}$ be the minimal primes of the noetherian ring $A$, and if $0\ne a\in \mathfrak{p_1}$ then $ab=0$ for some $b$, so $ab\in \mathfrak{p_i}$ for all $i$ then by reducedness $b\in \mathfrak{p_j}$ for some $j$ (else $a$ would be contained in nilradical). This says ideal $\mathfrak{p_1}$ would be zero when it is localized by primes not containing any other $\mathfrak{p_i}$'s. Hence support of $\mathcal{I_1}$ is in $X_2\cup X_3\cup \cdots \cup X_k$. We conclude the support of $\mathcal{I}_1\cdots\mathcal{I}_k$ is in intersection points, so the (sum of) skyscraper sheaf. From here, I don't know how to proceed; but maybe this is enough for cohomological induction. I would be happy if someone can give better proof.
Geometrically, I would say "if $f=0$ in $X_1$, then it is zero in some open subset (namely $X-X_2-\cdots-X_k$)". This is only true as we are considering irreducible components. Think about other general situation of $Z\subset X$ being a (codimension $\ge$ 1) closed subvariety. Now even $f=0$ on $Z$, it cannot be said "locally zero", i.e. it is not zero on any open neighborhood, or not a zero element in the structure sheaf. The ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}_Z$ consists of the functions being zero on $Z$, but they are not (even locally) zero on $Z$! Next step is more unclear, but if I try to think about how much sections in $\mathcal{I}_Z$ can be distinguished on $Z$, in the spirit of this, then somehow it could make sense that it can only distinguished up to first order.
